# Paragraph.BringIntoView() works only when focused

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, paragraph

I am working on a text editor that is based on RichEditBox. I have implemented functionality "Go to line" which eventually resolves to
`TextPointer.Paragraph.BringIntoView();`

Along with this I also set the caret position.
What I found out is that `BringIntoView` only works when I click on the `RichEditBox` first (focus it). Otherwise it seems to get ignored. I can see that the caret position has been adjusted by the code around BringIntoView though.

Does anybody know what is the reason/nature of that problem? How can I overcome it?

Comment: What langage/SDK are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I was so deep in the problem I forgot the details...
The project is in C# and WPF. I am using .NET 3.5
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm running into this as well, and I guess it's strongly related to [another issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9fdf56c-a651-4c9b-b0c6-9a74eca3840d/how-to-set-the-readonly-property-selection-on-a-flowdocumentscrollviewer?forum=wpf#2960f16a-c66d-4ef7-b91a-eadb655a3762) where the selection cannot be set before the user clicks inside the window. It's quite frustrating that Microsoft isn't fixing these problems. Feels like WPF is used by a small minority.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround for this, not sure if it will work in a pure WPF environment, in my case I'm running WPF inside a mainly Windows Forms solution using WPF UserControls where needed.

Instead of invoking BringIntoFocus() immediately, defer it to a later moment by adding it to a queue that gets handled by a timer. For example:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer DeferredActionTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 200 };

Queue<Action> DeferredActions = new Queue<Action>();

void DeferredActionTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  while(DeferredActions.Count > 0) {
    Action act = DeferredActions.Dequeue();
    act();
  }
}
```

In your forms constructor, or in the OnLoad event add:

```
DeferredActionTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(DeferredActionTimer_Tick);
DeferredActionTimer.Enabled = true;
```

Finally, instead of calling `TextPointer.Paragraph.BringIntoView();` directly, call it like this:

```
DeferredActions.Enqueue(() => TextPointer.Paragraph.BringIntoView());
```

Note that the Windows Forms timer kicks events off in the main thread (via the message pump loop). If you have to use another timer you need a bit of extra code. I'd recommend you to use `System.Timers.Timer` rather than the `System.Threading.Timer` (it's a little more thread-safe). You would also have to wrap the action in a `Dispatcher.Invoke` structure. In my case, the WinForms timer works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just give the `RichTextBox`(?) focus first then, using `Keyboard.Focus(richTextBox)` or `richTextBox.Focus()`?

Comment: Of course I tried that first. It doesn't help. But even if it does - that might be not quite correct (changing the focus) in the application UI context.